# How to detect which event fired applicationSignificantTimeChange

Tags: iphone, objective-c, time

How to detect which event (arrival of midnight or an update of the time by a carrier or the change to daylight savings time) has fired the applicationSignificantTimeChange method ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not doable with the SDK.

Comment: Because I need to detect ONLY update of time by the carrier but not by arrival of midnight ..

Comment: What is the harm in doing whatever you need to do in *all* cases where the event is fired?  Does it produce some user-visible action?

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat in this case:
check hour and minute in applicationSignificantTimeChange, if hour and minute is zero, it mean midnight or using a server time for validate

Comment: I researched this case and not found perfect solution, so use above solution with limit or change behavior of your app :|